# Magento Error when uploading a downloadable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I first was getting a max_upload_size issue, which I resolved by modifying php.ini.  I have increased it to 50M and I am getting a weird red box in Magento with no popup describing the error.  Does anyone have any experience with this error?

The log shows:

```
2013-09-10T19:37:27+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in /home/username/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 56826
```

Image showing error is here - http://s13.postimg.org/yb0my66t3/uploaderror.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being another php.ini setting that Magento didn't error handle

Changed post_max_size to 30M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 30M